# SQL In General / QODBC

Tags: sql, quickbooks

I am trying to select multiple names from a table within quickbooks / in general. 
Here is the sql statement I am using

```
 Select CustomerRefFullName from invoice where refNumber in ('5383', '5408')
```

Im trying to get it to return both the "CustomerRefFullName"s of the customers where refNumber is 5383 and 5408, but for some reason its only returning the CustomerRefFullName of 5383 and not 5408.

Any Ideas?
Thanks,
Canaan

Comment: Well, is there a row with refNumber 5408? :)

Comment: Jesus christ your a genius. Please answer that so I can check it... LOL

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the query in VB demo provided with the QODBC.  If error persist, then make sure that there is a Refnumber like 5408 on `Select * from invoice`.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
Select CustomerRefFullName from invoice UNOPTIMIZED where refNumber in ('5383', '5408')
```

or

```
Select CustomerRefFullName from invoice NOSYNC where refNumber in ('5383', '5408')
```